# Notation for H is isomorphic to a subgraph of G

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Is there a notation for the statement $H$ is isomorphic to a subgraph of $G$? I was thinking of using $H<G$, but I'd like to use standard notation if possible.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it would rather suggest "$H$ is a proper subgraph of $G$". $H\le G$ might be closer to what you want (at least allowing $H=G$); I don't know if it's used in a distinct meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the $\simeq$ notation for isomorphic structures, I would suggest $\lesssim$, $\prec$, $\precsim$, or [this symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108403/how-to-create-subset-with-sim-symbol).

The pair of symbols $\prec$ and $\precsim$ have the advantage of providing a symbol for both allowing and discarding equality.

Comment: I'd interpret this as induced subgraph, as there seems to be a suggestion of morphism here.